# Read stream from input channel

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

it is possible to read the stream from an input channel without creating a new function and add the streamListenner annotation. I'm using spring cloud stream.

Thanks!

EDIT

Actually, I'm creating a microservice, where I have this method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/annonces")
public void addAnnonce(@RequestBody AnnonceWrapper annonceWrapper) {
    final Message<AnnonceWrapper> message = MessageBuilder
                                                    .withPayload(annonceWrapper)
                                                    .setReplyChannel(messageStream.addAnnonceInput())
                                                    .build();
    this.messageStream.addAnnonceOutput().send(message);
}
```

This method should receive from the subscribe channel addAnnonceInput() the json that will be returned by the current function. the probleme is how i can read the stream from the addAnnonceInput() channel.

Comment: Hi, Can you elaborate a bit more in your question? Not sure what do you mean by 'without creating a new function`. Thanks!

Comment: So, is your microservice sending messages to another microservice? I suppose then that the receiving microservice will need to do some processing on the message - so it will need to have some logic that subscribes to the input channel - it's not very clear why would you want to avoid that?

Comment: I didn't avoid it, the other microservice did the processing needed and send back the result, that i can receive if i create a method with the streamListenner annotation. but i need to receive this result in addAnnonce method in order to send it back to the client.