# PollableChannel in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-stream

How I can use PollableChannel in Spring Cloud Stream to receive a stream from inputs?
Thanks

Comment: Please, elaborate more why do you need that?

Comment: Receive a stream from a channel without creating a new method and add the StreamListenner annotation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821377/read-stream-from-input-channel

Comment: Presumably is is related to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821377/read-stream-from-input-channel). The annotation causes a lot of plumbing work to be done for you. You need to explain your use case better, but it is likely you will be better off using Spring Integration support for Spring AMQP (for rabbit) or Spring Kafka (for Apache Kafka) directly in your boot app.

Comment: What is a stream in your terms? There is a `@BridgeFrom`/`@BridgeTo` for your info. Please, share some code to understand where you are

Comment: I mean data sent by a microservice, as I know to receive data in Spring cloud stream you will need to create a method annotated with stream listener, in my case I need to receive this data inside a method without an any annotation.

Comment: No-op. You are still unclear. Some code on the matter? What do you have already? What would you like to change? This works well, this doesn't and so on, so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You even don't need that `@StreamListener` annotation to receive data from the Binder. Just provide `@EnableBinding(Processor.class)` for your microservise and inject a bean like:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(Processor.INPUT)
private MessageChannel inputChannel;
```

And subscribe to it manually.

Or you can use any Spring Integration approach to subscribe to that `MessageChannel`, e.g.:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow myProcess() {
   return IntegrationFlows.from(Processor.INPUT)
          ...
          .get();

}
```

The  `@StreamListener` is fully distinguished from the binding.

Comment: I did the first service, but the problem is subscribed doesn't return the received data that I need to return to the client, it returns void

Comment: Well, you can use `ReplyAddress` pattern to specify some channel, destination or anything else in the request message headers and wait for the reply from that `ReplyAddress`. If everything is in-memory you can just use `@MessagingGateway`, which hides that pattern for you.